# PdfBox - Get font Information using

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, annotations, pdfbox

I'm trying to get text from pdf using `Square Annotation`. I use below code to extract text from PDF using `PDFBOX.`
**CODE**

```
try {    
            PDDocument document = null;
            try {
                document = PDDocument.load(new File("//Users//" + usr + "//Desktop//BoldTest2 2.pdf"));
                List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
                for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
                    PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
                    Map<String, PDFont> pageFonts = page.getResources().getFonts();
                    List<PDAnnotation> la = page.getAnnotations();
                    for (int f = 0; f < la.size(); f++) {
                        PDAnnotation pdfAnnot = la.get(f);
                        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
                        PDRectangle rect = pdfAnnot.getRectangle();

                        float x = 0;
                        float y = 0;
                        float width = 0;
                        float height = 0;
                        int rotation = page.findRotation();

                        if (rotation == 0) {
                            x = rect.getLowerLeftX();
                            y = rect.getUpperRightY() - 2;
                            width = rect.getWidth();
                            height = rect.getHeight();
                            PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
                            y = pageSize.getHeight() - y;
                        }
                        Rectangle2D.Float awtRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
                        stripper.addRegion(Integer.toString(f), awtRect);
                        stripper.extractRegions(page);
                        PrintTextLocation2 prt = new PrintTextLocation2();
                        if (pdfAnnot.getSubtype().equals("Square")) {
                            testTxt = testTxt + "\n " + stripper.getTextForRegion(Integer.toString(f));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                if (document != null) {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
```

By using this code, I am only able to get the PDF text. How do I do to get the font information like **BOLD** *ITALIC* together within the text. Advice or references are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878170/how-to-determine-artificial-bold-style-artificial-italic-style-and-artificial-o/20924898#20924898) to see the *general procedure* (deriving from `PDFTextStripper` and overriding `writeString`) and the current issue with it. The `TextPosition` instances given to that method contain some information about the font and the rest of the currnt state while drawing the text. Whether you have to derive the style information from the font itself or from some graphics state, depends on how the style is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PDFTextStripper` which is extended by `PDFTextStripperByArea` normalizes (i.e., removes formatting of) the text (cf. [JavaDoc comment](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.java)):

```
* This class will take a pdf document and strip out all of the text and ignore the
* formatting and such.
```

If you look at the source, you will see that the font information is available in this class, but it is normalized out before printing:

```
protected void writePage() throws IOException
{
    [...]
        List<TextPosition> line = new ArrayList<TextPosition>();
        [...]
            if(!overlap(positionY, positionHeight, maxYForLine, maxHeightForLine))
            {
                writeLine(normalize(line,isRtlDominant,hasRtl),isRtlDominant);
                line.clear();
                [...]
            }
............
```

The `TextPosition` instances in the ArrayList have all the formatting information. Solutions can focus on re-defining the existing methods as per the requirement. I am listing a few options below:

- private List normalize(List line, boolean isRtlDominant, boolean hasRtl)

If you want your own `normalize` method, you can copy the whole [`PDFTextStripper`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.java) class in your project and change the code of the copy. Let's call this new class as `MyPDFTextStripper` and then define new method as per the requirement. Similarly copy [`PDFTextStripperByArea`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripperByArea.java) as `MyPDFTextStripperByArea` which would extend `MyPDFTextStripper`.

- protected void writePage()

If you just need a new `writePage` method, you can simply extend [`PDFTextStripper`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.java), and override this method, then create `MyPDFTextStripperByArea` as described above.

- writeLine(normalize(line,isRtlDominant,hasRtl),isRtlDominant)

Other solution might override writeLine method by storing the `pre-normalization` information in some variable and then using it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Depending on which of the mentioned approaches you take, you may be subject to the PDFBox issue [PDFBOX-1804](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1804) which presumably will be resolved as of version 1.8.4.

Comment: Have you any idea how to leave, lets say, only "bold" feature of the text?