# How to determine artificial bold style ,artificial italic style and artificial outline style of a text using PDFBOX

Tags: pdf, font-size, detect, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox for validating a pdf document .
There are certain requirement to check following types of text present in a PDF

- Artificial Bold style text
- Artificial italic style text.
- Artificial outline style text

I did search in PDFBOX api list  but was unable to find such kind of api.

Can anyone please help me out and tell how to determine different types of artificial font/text styles to be present in a PDF using PDFBOX.

Comment: I do not seem to have the permissions to access your sample document. That been said, there are multiple ways to e.g. bold-ify some output. Do you want to find as many ways as possible? Or just one specific way?

Comment: Apologies for making the PDF as private content.However I have already made the sample PDF as Public.It will be really great if you could show the best ways to do these checks....Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have started looking into your sample document. The artificial italics style is ready, merely some special effect of the text matrix. The artificial bold, though, is very verbose; unnecessarily so I assume, but maybe there are certain devices requiring that. I'll come back later.

Comment: Hi mkl,Did you get an opportunity to look into that issue.

Comment: Yes, and I was somewhat surprised by a behavior of PDFBox. I'm looking into it some more.

Comment: Ok, I now know the PDFBox issue resulting in the surprising PDFBox behavior. You can find it in my initial answer. I'll look into the details and say more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The general procedure and a PDFBox issue

In theory one should start this by deriving a class from `PDFTextStripper` and overriding its method:

```
/**
 * Write a Java string to the output stream. The default implementation will ignore the <code>textPositions</code>
 * and just calls {@link #writeString(String)}.
 *
 * @param text The text to write to the stream.
 * @param textPositions The TextPositions belonging to the text.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error when writing the text.
 */
protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{
    writeString(text);
}
```

Your override then should use `List<TextPosition> textPositions` instead of the `String text`; each `TextPosition` essentially represents a single a single letter and the information on the graphic state active when that letter was drawn.

Unfortunately the `textPositions` list does **not** contain the correct contents in the current version 1.8.3. E.g. for the line "This is normal text." from your PDF the method `writeString` is called four times, once each for the strings "This", " is", " normal", and " text." Unfortunately the `textPositions` list each time contains the `TextPosition` instances for the letters of the last string " text."

This actually proved to have already been recognized as PDFBox issue [PDFBOX-1804](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1804) which meanwhile has been resolved as fixed for versions 1.8.4 and 2.0.0.

This been said, as soon as you have a PDFBox version which is fixed, you can check for some artificial styles as follows:

### Artificial italic text

This text style is created like this in the page content:

```
BT
/F0 1 Tf
24 0 5.10137 24 66 695.5877 Tm
0 Tr
[<03>]TJ
...
```

The relevant part happens in setting the text matrix **Tm**. The 5.10137 is a factor by which the text is sheared.

When you check a `TextPosition textPosition` as indicated above, you can query this value using

```
textPosition.getTextPos().getValue(1, 0)
```

If this value relevantly is greater than 0.0, you have artificial italics. If it is relevantly less than 0.0, you have artificial backwards italics.

### Artificial bold or outline text

These artificial styles use double printing letters using differing rendering modes; e.g. the capital 'T', in case of bold:

```
0 0 0 1 k
...
BT
/F0 1 Tf 
24 0 0 24 66.36 729.86 Tm 
<03>Tj 
4 M 0.72 w 
0 0 Td 
1 Tr 
0 0 0 1 K
<03>Tj
ET
```

(i.e. first drawing the letter in regular mode, filling the letter area, and then drawing it in outline mode, drawing a line along the letter border, both in black, CMYK 0, 0, 0, 1; this leaves the impression of a thicker letter.)

and in case of outline:

```
BT
/F0 1 Tf
24 0 0 24 66 661.75 Tm
0 0 0 0 k
<03>Tj
/GS1 gs
4 M 0.288 w 
0 0 Td
1 Tr
0 0 0 1 K
<03>Tj
ET
```

(i.e. first drawing the letter in regular mode white, CMYK 0, 0, 0, 0, filling the letter area, and then drawing it in outline mode, drawing a line along the letter border, in black, CMYK 0, 0, 0, 1; this leaves the impression of an outlined black on white letter.)

Unfortunately the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` does not keep track of the text rendering mode. Furthermore it explicitly drops duplicate character occurrences in approximately the same position. Thus, it is not up to the task of recognizing these artificial styles.

If you really need to do so, you'd have to change `TextPosition` to also contain the rendering mode, `PDFStreamEngine` to add it to the generated `TextPosition` instances, and `PDFTextStripper` to *not* drop duplicate glyphs in `processTextPosition`.

### Corrections

I wrote

> Unfortunately the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` does not keep track of the text rendering mode.

This is not entirely true, you can find the *current* rendering mode using `getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode()`. This means that during `processTextPosition` you do have the rendering mode available and can try and store rendering mode (and color!) information for the given `TextPosition` somewhere, e.g. in some `Map<TextPosition, ...>`, for later use.

> Furthermore it explicitly drops duplicate character occurrences in approximately the same position.

You can disable this by calling `setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false)`.

With these two changes you should be able to make the required tests for checking for artificial bold and outline, too.

The latter change might even not be necessary if you store and check for the styles early in `processTextPosition`.

### How to retrieve rendering mode and color

As mentioned in *Corrections* it indeed *is* possible to retrieve rendering mode and color information by collecting that information in a `processTextPosition` override.

To this the OP commented that

> Always the stroking and non-stroking color is coming as Black

This was a bit surprising at first but after looking at the `PDFTextStripper.properties` (from which the operators supported during text extraction are initialized), the reason became clear:

```
# The following operators are not relevant to text extraction,
# so we can silently ignore them.
...
K
k
```

Thus color setting operators (especially those for CMYK colors as in the present document) are ignored in this context! Fortunately the implementations of these operators for the `PageDrawer` can be used in this context, too.

So the following proof-of-concept shows how all required information can be retrieved.

```
public class TextWithStateStripperSimple extends PDFTextStripper
{
    public TextWithStateStripperSimple() throws IOException {
        super();
        setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
        registerOperatorProcessor("K", new org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetStrokingCMYKColor());
        registerOperatorProcessor("k", new org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetNonStrokingCMYKColor());
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
    {
        renderingMode.put(text, getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode());
        strokingColor.put(text, getGraphicsState().getStrokingColor());
        nonStrokingColor.put(text, getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor());

        super.processTextPosition(text);
    }

    Map<TextPosition, Integer> renderingMode = new HashMap<TextPosition, Integer>();
    Map<TextPosition, PDColorState> strokingColor = new HashMap<TextPosition, PDColorState>();
    Map<TextPosition, PDColorState> nonStrokingColor = new HashMap<TextPosition, PDColorState>();

    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        writeString(text + '\n');

        for (TextPosition textPosition: textPositions)
        {
            StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            textBuilder.append(textPosition.getCharacter())
                       .append(" - shear by ")
                       .append(textPosition.getTextPos().getValue(1, 0))
                       .append(" - ")
                       .append(textPosition.getX())
                       .append(" ")
                       .append(textPosition.getY())
                       .append(" - ")
                       .append(renderingMode.get(textPosition))
                       .append(" - ")
                       .append(toString(strokingColor.get(textPosition)))
                       .append(" - ")
                       .append(toString(nonStrokingColor.get(textPosition)))
                       .append('\n');
            writeString(textBuilder.toString());
        }
    }

    String toString(PDColorState colorState)
    {
        if (colorState == null)
            return "null";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (float f: colorState.getColorSpaceValue())
        {
            builder.append(' ')
                   .append(f);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Using this you get the period '.' in normal text as:

```
. - shear by 0.0 - 256.5701 88.6875 - 0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

In artificial bold text you get;

```
. - shear by 0.0 - 378.86 122.140015 - 0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
. - shear by 0.0 - 378.86002 122.140015 - 1 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

In artificial italics:

```
. - shear by 5.10137 - 327.121 156.4123 - 0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

And in artificial outline:

```
. - shear by 0.0 - 357.25 190.25 - 0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
. - shear by 0.0 - 357.25 190.25 - 1 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

So, there you are, all information required for recognition of those artificial styles. Now you merely have to analyze the data.

BTW, have a look at the artificial bold case: The coordinates might not always be identical but instead merely very similar. Thus, some leniency is required for the test whether two text position objects describe the same position.

Comment: Thanks.Does that means I need to download the fixed PDFBOX version which have the Text Stripper problem fixed?For a large PDF does the PDfTextStripper function called each time for each and every text?

Comment: Also I am currently using PDFBOX-1.7.1.jar where I could not find TextStripper class having method writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions).It has only one method called writeString(String text).

Comment: The method overload including the list of `TextPosition` instances has been added last November to allow the extraction of additional style information. Thus, it has been released first time in 1.8.3. Older PDFBox versions require much more extended changes in `PDFTextStripper` descendants.

Comment: Hi MKl,Sorry for the latest communication gap,I was outside of the town.Coming back to your answer I have one query.Any idea when the new version(1.8.4) is going to be available?is there any way we can apply patch to use of the valid PDFTextStripper functionality.

Comment: I don't know their release schedule. But PDFBox is open source and the current development state of the library can be downloaded from the source control of the Apache Foundation, you can easily build a jar already containing the fix.

Comment: Hi Mkl,Is it possible for you to just provide any code snippet for artificial bold and artificial outline.It will be really helpful.

Comment: Furthermore when I try to get Text renderingMode() from PDTextStripper class using getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode() it is always coming as 0.does that means it is always as RENDERING_MODE_FILL_TEXT.

Comment: *getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode()* - Ah, yes, you of course have the graphic state there. Call the text stripper method `setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false)` before processing the page. Now you should get differing rendering modes.

Comment: Yes you are right.Now i am geeting different rendering mode.For some letter it is come as 0 and for some it is as 1(RENDERING_MODE_STROKE_TEXT).But i am not sure which one to consider.Do i need to check color of the text also.Means if color=black and rendering mode=1 then artificial bold,if color=white and rendering mode=1 the artificial outline.Further more both stroking and non-stroking color iscoming as black.But i am unable to determine the filling color between two text for bold and outline.Any suggestion?

Comment: *Means if...* - As mentioned above artificial bold and outline are done using two drawing operations. Thus, you have to look for pairs of text drawing operations for the same text in the same location with differing tendering modes and check the colors used in them.

Comment: Got it,But could not able to determine filling color.Always the stroking and non-stroking color is coming as Black.Not able to differenciate between bold and outline.

Comment: That should not happen. Maybe there is a bug, either in your code or in PDFBox. If you added your current code to the question, I could look into it.

Comment: Ah, it's not a bug, it's a limitation by design... which fortunately can easily be lifted, cf my latest edit "How to retrieve rendering mode and color"

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was to create a new class that extends the PDFTextStripper class and overrides the function:

> `getCharactersByArticle()`

*note: PDFBox version 1.8.5*

**CustomPDFTextStripper class**

```
public class CustomPDFTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper
{
    public CustomPDFTextStripper() throws IOException {
    super();
    }

    public Vector<List<TextPosition>> getCharactersByArticle(){
    return charactersByArticle;
    }
}
```

This way i can parse the pdf document and then get the TextPosition from a custom extraction function:

```
 private void extractTextPosition() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(pdf));
    parser.parse();
    StringWriter outString = new StringWriter();
    CustomPDFTextStripper stripper = new CustomPDFTextStripper();
    stripper.writeText(parser.getPDDocument(), outString);
    Vector<List<TextPosition>> vectorlistoftps = stripper.getCharactersByArticle();
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorlistoftps.size(); i++) {
        List<TextPosition> tplist = vectorlistoftps.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < tplist.size(); j++) {
            TextPosition text = tplist.get(j);
            System.out.println(" String "
          + "[x: " + text.getXDirAdj() + ", y: "
          + text.getY() + ", height:" + text.getHeightDir()
          + ", space: " + text.getWidthOfSpace() + ", width: "
          + text.getWidthDirAdj() + ", yScale: " + text.getYScale() + "]"
          + text.getCharacter());
        }       
    }
}
```

TextPositions contain numerous information about the characters of the pdf document.

**OUTPUT:**

> String [x: 168.24, y: 64.15997, height:6.061287, space: 8.9664, width:3.4879303, yScale: 8.9664]J
>
> String [x: 171.69745, y: 64.15997, height:6.061287, space: 8.9664, width: 2.2416077, yScale:8.9664]N
>
> String [x: 176.25777, y: 64.15997, height:6.0343876, space: 8.9664,width: 6.4737396, yScale:8.9664]N
>
> String [x: 182.73778, y:64.15997, height:4.214208, space: 8.9664, width: 3.981079, yScale: 8.9664]e .....

Comment: *TextPositions contain numerous information about the characters of the pdf document* - but **not** rendering mode and colors which are information required for the OP's task.