# PDFBOX - Extract highlighted text that has been set with microsoft word

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, itext, pdfbox

I have a PDF file, this file contains some text and some highlighted text. The highligthed text has not been set with a PDF editor but with Microsoft Word (so this file is a "Print to PDF" word file).

I would like to extract/detect the highlighted text, and if it's possible the color.

I searched and tried different code and my results are :

- I can extract the highlighted text if it has been highlighted with PDF editor
- I can't extract the highlighted text if it has been highlighted with word

I would like to know if you have any idea how to extract this highlighted text that isn't set with a PDF editor.

I followed this thread :

[Identifying the text based on the output in PDF using PDFBOX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430341/identifying-the-text-based-on-the-output-in-pdf-using-pdfbox?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I would like to get (if possible) a result like this :

> H{FILL:RGB 0.102 0.101 0.095;}E{FILL:RGB 0.102 0.101 0.095;}L{FILL:RGB
> 0.102 0.101 0.095;}L{FILL:RGB 0.102 0.101 0.095;}O{FILL:RGB 0.102 0.101 0.095;}

But with the highlighted color of each character and not the character color.

I tried many things, i can't find a way to extract which part of my PDF is highlighted or not.

I have no more idea i can do...

I hope someone can help me !

Comment: Please share a representative example PDF.

Comment: https://uploadnow.io/f/BMfflX9 here is a pdf exemple (not allowed to share the real one because of confidentials informations)

Comment: thank you for your answers, i thought the art and text would be connected. so this is not really possible, in Java, to detect which character is hightlighted ?

Comment: if anyone has any idea... i'm desperate :')