# Using PDFBox to get location of line of text

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to extract information from a pdf, and the information I'm currently trying to find is related to the x-position of the first character in the line.  I can't find anything related to how to get that information though.  I know pdfbox has a class called TextPosition, but I can't find out how to get a TextPosition object from the PDDocument either.  How do I get the location information of a line of text from a pdf?

Comment: There are multiple samples showing how to get `TextPosition` objects  from a document, e.g. [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924898/1729265) in the section *The general procedure and a PDFBox issue*. The *issue* meanwhile has been resolved.

Comment: @mkl How is writeString called?  It's protected, so it's likely called from within another method in TextStripper, but I'm not sure which one.  I tried the solution in the next answer, about the charactersByArticle, but the vector I got as a result was empty.

Comment: *How is writeString called* - you apply a `PDFTextStripper` instance to your document and that instance calls `writeString` again and again.

Comment: *I tried the solution in the next answer, about the charactersByArticle* - that only makes sense for pdfs which contain certain additional meta information separating multiple articles in the document. If your PDF does not have such information, `charactersByArticle` won't help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to looking at pdfs, and I feel like you're referencing things you think I should know but I don't.  You say apply a PDFTextStripper instance to my document and that will do it, but how do I do that?  I've tried calling startDocument and getText, and neither of those ran the code in the new writeString method.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and write something up later. Currently I'm on a smart phone which is not optimal for providing in-depth samples.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### In general

To extract text (with or without extra information like positions, colors, etc.) using PDFBox, you instantiate a `PDFTextStripper` or a class derived from it and use it like this:

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

(There are a number of `PDFTextStripper` attributes allowing you to restrict the pages text is extracted from.)

In the course of the execution of `getText` the content streams of the pages in question (and those of form xObjects referenced from those pages) are parsed and text drawing commands are processed.

If you want to change the text extraction behavior, you have to change this text drawing command processing which you most often should do by overriding this method:

```
/**
 * Write a Java string to the output stream. The default implementation will ignore the <code>textPositions</code>
 * and just calls {@link #writeString(String)}.
 *
 * @param text The text to write to the stream.
 * @param textPositions The TextPositions belonging to the text.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error when writing the text.
 */
protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{
    writeString(text);
}
```

If you additionally need to know when a new line starts, you may also want to override

```
/**
 * Write the line separator value to the output stream.
 * @throws IOException
 *             If there is a problem writing out the lineseparator to the document.
 */
protected void writeLineSeparator( ) throws IOException
{
    output.write(getLineSeparator());
}
```

`writeString` can be overridden to channel the text information into separate members (e.g. if you might want a result in a more structured format than a mere `String`) or it can be overridden to simply add some extra information into the result `String`.

`writeLineSeparator` can be overridden to trigger some specific output between lines.

There are more methods which can be overridden but you are less likely to need them in general.

---

### In the case at hand

> I'm using PDFBox to extract information from a pdf, and the information I'm currently trying to find is related to the x-position of the first character in the line.

This can be implemented as follows (simply adding the information at the start of each line):

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
{
    @Override
    protected void startPage(PDPage page) throws IOException
    {
        startOfLine = true;
        super.startPage(page);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeLineSeparator() throws IOException
    {
        startOfLine = true;
        super.writeLineSeparator();
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        if (startOfLine)
        {
            TextPosition firstProsition = textPositions.get(0);
            writeString(String.format("[%s]", firstProsition.getXDirAdj()));
            startOfLine = false;
        }
        super.writeString(text, textPositions);
    }
    boolean startOfLine = true;
};

text = stripper.getText(document);
```

*([ExtractText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractText.java) method `extractLineStart` tested by `testExtractLineStartFromSampleFile`)*

Comment: This answer helped me tremendously.  I also found my problem before with calling getText, I had put in a getText function myself before I knew to extend PDFTextStripper, and that was keeping it from calling the new writeString function.  Thanks!

Comment: @Beez can you share your code, i am also stuck with this type of problem. I want to change the color blue to black from text (which starts with 'http' OR 'https').