# How to find specific text position (coordinates) and drawImage on this position?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I need to find some text in a pdf document and put an image there, such as:
"My car" in a document and place the image below / next to that text.

```
{.....
BufferedImage image = resizeImage(base64Picture, pictureScaling);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(base64Pdf);
int lastPage = document.getNumberOfPages()-1;
PDPage page = document.getPage(lastPage);  
PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, image);
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);

// find location of "My car"

contents.drawImage(); // draw image below / next to "My car"

.....}
```

Comment: For PdfBox you find multiple questions and answers on the topic of extracting text with coordinates, e.g.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514745/1729265), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46080131/1729265), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027322/1729265). You merely need to follow these examples and look for "My car" in the analyzed text with coordinates.

Comment: If it is a one time only thing, then use PDFDebugger to see the coordinates (move the mouse).

Comment: Thanks for advice...@Tilman Hausherr, the document should be dynamic